# Installing XFree86 on imx6 Debian Board

Tags: debian, apt, x11, arm

I should install **XFree86** on my **Debian** running **imx6 arm** board, But it says it has **no installation candidate**.

I have already tried **apt installing** it.

```
debian@sr-imx6:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xfree86
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xserver-xfree86 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xserver-xfree86' has no installation candidate
```

I need it because **Qt 5** applications I compile, gives error when I try to **execute** them.

```
debian@sr-imx6:~$ ./Qt5_CinematicExperience
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 147 (Unknown), sequence: 179, resource id: 49, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 9
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 181, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
Segmentation fault
```

Well, my **system information** output,

```
debian@sr-imx6:~$ uname -a
Linux sr-imx6 4.9.150-imx6-sr #1 SMP Sat Jun 22 06:22:03 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I want to use **XFree86** instead of **Xorg** because I think, **GPU drivers** for my X11 Debian board, **imx-gpu-viv-x11**, does not support **Xorg**, but **XFree86**. As I mentioned, when I try to execute CPP applications, It gives that error, *Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0"*, and then a **segmentation fault** error.

Comment: Two questions. (1) What exact architecture is this? (For ARM, the obvious ones I see supported by current Debian releases is arm64, armel and armhf.) (2) Why do you want to install XFree86, rather than Xorg? Please [Edit] your question to answer.

Comment: @aCVn Hello, thanks for your response, I have edited my topic. The issue still goes on.